# Footer template for CSV export for Angular ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have the logic for exporting the data to CSV. However I wanted to add a disclaimer at the bottom of the exported grid. I see that this functionality is provided for PDF but I don't see it for CSV. Does angular-ui grid provide the functionality for this scenario.

Comment: Could you figure how to do this?

Comment: The only workaround I found that worked for me was to insert empty rows in the grid and then write the disclaimer to it before exporting to CSV/PDF and then deleting the extra rows from the grid. This seems to work, the only drawback is that the grid flashes when you export because of the insertion and deletion of rows.